# Возврат даты в русском формате

Tags: javascript, функции, дата

Здравствуйте, мне дана строка и надо было написать функцию, которая принимает эту строку, и возвращает её в русском формате. У меня такой код, но не пойму в чём ошибка?

```js
let date = new Date("29, 03, 1985");
function getZero(num){
 if (num > 0 && num < 10) { 
  return '0' + num;
 } else {
  return num;
 }
}

console.log(getZero(date.getDate()) + '.' + getZero(date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: формат для Date неподходящий ... "год, месяц, день"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Доброе утро.

```js
  var options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  timezone: 'UTC'
};
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString("ru", options));
```

Или замените **month: 'numeric'** на **month: 'long',** и получите название месяца строкой.

Подробней о [toLocaleString()](http://learn.javascript.ru/datetime#%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82)

Comment: Спасибо. О как мне не хватало этой функции, всегда делал примерно так как автор вопроса. Теперь буду знать как это делать правильно.

Comment: Хорошо бы в ответ ещё ссылочку поместить где можно подробно прочитать про эти настройки.

Comment: Дмитрий, дополнил ответ ссылкой.

Comment: Не прямой ответ на вопрос, но не отметить `(+)-ом`, грех))))....

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался!)

Comment: Ну почему же не прямой? Автор вопрос как написать функцию. Но в js есть уже всё для того, чтобы вывести дату в нужном формате. Так зачем "платить лишнее"?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь создать дату из строки, но формат строки выбран не верно.
Что бы создать дату из строки строка должна соответсnвовать стандартным правилам [Date.parse](http://javascript.ru/date.parse).

```js
let date = new Date("1980.11.20");
function getZero(num){
 if (num > 0 && num < 10) { 
  return '0' + num;
 } else {
  return num;
 }
}

console.log(getZero(date.getDate()) + '.' + getZero(date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + date.getFullYear());
```

Читаем тут - [Date](http://javascript.ru/Date).

В вашем случае сначала подготавливаем данные.

```js
let str = "29, 03, 1985";
let dataTokens = str.split(",");

let date = new Date(+dataTokens[2], +dataTokens[1] - 1, +dataTokens[0]);

function getZero(num) {
  if (num > 0 && num < 10) {
    return '0' + num;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}

console.log(getZero(date.getDate()) + '.' + getZero(date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + date.getFullYear());
```